# My application won't modify text as it should when nested inside another class?

Tags: java, android

The code below for Android is supposed to modify the statement "Hello World!" to say "TODAY IS AUGUST SEVENTH" today, and say "ERROR" any other day of the year. However, all I get is "Hello World!" The strange thing is, I ran the code exactly the same way on an entirely new program, but without nesting the class CheckDate inside the class FirstFragment. I attempted to solve this by just removing the FirstFragment class, but that causes an error in my MainActivity class, which I used to create a sidebar application for the application. Is there anything I can do to keep the side bar, and make the app modify the text "Hello World!" to what it should say?

***FIRST FRAGMENT***

```
package com.example.gcsd.gcsdapp;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.icu.util.Calendar;
import android.icu.util.GregorianCalendar;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.icu.util.GregorianCalendar;
import android.icu.util.Calendar;

public class FirstFragment extends Fragment {

View myView;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup 
container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home, container, false);
return myView;

}

public class CheckDate extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

    GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();

    System.out.println(cal.get(Calendar.DATE)); //prints 4
    System.out.println(cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1); //this starts at 0, not 1. Therefore, add 1
    System.out.println(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR)); //2017

    if ((cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + 0 == 4) && (cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1 == 8)) { //Is it the fourth of the month of 2017?
        System.out.println("TODAY IS AUGUST FOURTH");
        textView.setText("TODAY IS AUGUST FOURTH");
    } else {
        System.out.println("ERROR");
        textView.setText("ERROR");
    }

}
}
}
```

***First Fragment$CheckDate.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.gcsd.gcsdapp.FirstFragment$CheckDate">

<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/textView"
android:text="Hello World!"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

***MAIN ACTIVITY***

```
package com.example.gcsd.gcsdapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", 
Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .setAction("Action", null).show();
    }
});

DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
        this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, 
R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
toggle.syncState();

NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
} else {
    super.onBackPressed();
}
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
// Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
// Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
// automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
// as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
int id = item.getItemId();

//noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
    return true;
}

return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
// Handle navigation view item clicks here.
int id = item.getItemId();
android.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

if (id == R.id.nav_home) {
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.content_frame
                    , new FirstFragment())
            .commit();
} else if (id == R.id.nav_events) {
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.content_frame
                    , new SecondFragment())
            .commit();
} else if (id == R.id.nav_schooltool) {
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.content_frame
                    , new ThirdFragment())
            .commit();
} else if (id == R.id.nav_lessonreminders) {
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.content_frame
                    , new FourthFragment())
            .commit();
} else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

} else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

}

DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
return true;
}
}
```

Comment: the question is fine, but slightly hard to read - I'd make more paragraphs, emphasize question,... it will attract more people and you might get faster/better answer

Answer (score 0):

Replace your First Fragment class with below code

```
package com.example.gcsd.gcsdapp;

    import android.app.Fragment;
    import android.icu.util.Calendar;
    import android.icu.util.GregorianCalendar;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.icu.util.GregorianCalendar;
    import android.icu.util.Calendar;

    public class FirstFragment extends Fragment {

    View myView;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup 
    container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.checkdate, container, false);

        TextView textView = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.textView);

        GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();

        System.out.println(cal.get(Calendar.DATE)); //prints 4
        System.out.println(cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1); //this starts at 0, not 1. Therefore, add 1
        System.out.println(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR)); //2017

        if ((cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + 0 == 4) && (cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1 == 8)) { //Is it the fourth of the month of 2017?
            System.out.println("TODAY IS AUGUST FOURTH");
            textView.setText("TODAY IS AUGUST FOURTH");
        } else {
            System.out.println("ERROR");
            textView.setText("ERROR");
        }
    return myView;

    }
  }
```